# Calling 3rd party API causes "Too many open files." error due to number of CLOSE_WAIT files

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, bigcommerce

I'm using the Bigcommerce PHP SDK in my application. This SDK is documented here:

https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php

I have a script that iterates over a large array of objects (1000's of objects). During each iteration, many calls are made to Bigcommerce using this SDK. For example in one file in the script here might be a call to get the skus for a product:

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'client_id' => BC_CLIENT_ID,
    'auth_token' => BC_AUTH_TOKEN,
    'store_hash' => BC_STORE_HASH,
));

Bigcommerce::getCollection('product/123/skus', 'Sku');
```

Then later on in another file used in the script, there is a call to retrieve another resource, like the images for a product:

```
Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'client_id' => BC_CLIENT_ID,
    'auth_token' => BC_AUTH_TOKEN,
    'store_hash' => BC_STORE_HASH,
));

Bigcommerce::getCollection('product/123/images', 'Sku');
```

The problem I'm having is that after this script runs for a while, I get an error saying there are too many files open. Here's the actual error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include(/var/www/html/app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files' in /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:386
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(386): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/html/a...', 386, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(386): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(278): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/html/a...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...')
#4 /var/www/html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/WhoopsDisplayer.php(49): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\Compone...')
#5 /var/www/html/app/ve in /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 386

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include(/var/www/html/app/vendor/symfony/debug/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files' in /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:386
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(386): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(2, 'include(/var/ww...', '/var/www/html/a...', 386, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(386): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(278): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/html/a...')
#3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Symfony\Compone...')
#4 /var/www/html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Exception/Handler.php(191): spl_autoload_call('Symfony\Compone...')
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Hand in /var/www/html/app/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 386
```

I've been able to determine that as the script is running, each connection made to Bigcommerce seems to count as another "file" that is open. I see this by running the following command:

```
lsof -uroot | grep 104.236.XX.XXX | wc -l
```

The number output by this command keeps increasing. If I actually look at the open files, I can see a very long list of files with the state `CLOSE_WAIT`, for example:

```
php       14005 root    5u     IPv4            1792827      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58077->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root    7u     IPv4            1793002      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58078->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root    8u     IPv4            1793003      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58079->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root    9u     IPv4            1793004      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58080->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   10u     IPv4            1793005      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58081->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   11u     IPv4            1793006      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58082->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   12u     IPv4            1793007      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58083->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   13u     IPv4            1793008      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58084->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   14u     IPv4            1793093      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58085->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   15u     IPv4            1793094      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58086->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   16u     IPv4            1793095      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58087->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   17u     IPv4            1793170      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58088->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   18u     IPv4            1793234      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58089->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   19u     IPv4            1793242      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58090->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   20u     IPv4            1793315      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58091->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   21u     IPv4            1793328      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58092->192.200.169.163:https (CLOSE_WAIT)
php       14005 root   22u     IPv4            1793389      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58093->192.200.169.163:https (ESTABLISHED)
php       14005 root   23u     IPv4            1793390      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58094->192.200.169.163:https (ESTABLISHED)
php       14005 root   24u     IPv4            1793458      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58095->192.200.169.163:https (ESTABLISHED)
php       14005 root   25u     IPv4            1793464      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58096->192.200.169.163:https (ESTABLISHED)
php       14005 root   26u     IPv4            1793465      0t0     TCP 104.236.XX.XXX:58097->192.200.169.163:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

This list continue to get longer and longer until the script errors out with the "Too many files open" error I showed above.

My assumption is that these `CLOSE_WAIT` files are causing me to hit the limit of the amount of files that can be open. Is there anything I can do to get rid of these files? Why are they considered "open" files if the connection to Bigcommerce is already completed?

Perhaps I am using the SDK incorrectly? In other words, is there a way to make all of the calls come from the single `Bigcommerce` class rather than creating a new connection every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by altering the `configure` method to not create a new connection every time it's called. The new method is available in my fork on github:

https://github.com/flyingL123/bigcommerce-api-php

Comment: I am getting the same issue, can you please let me know where I need to make changes to solve this issue

Comment: @Arjunsingh This was so long ago. I apologize I can't remember, but I think it was something to do with this commit: https://github.com/flyingL123/bigcommerce-api-php/commit/c186dbdc0c872c662c64885920f111e9c1b1057b. I remember the library was creating a new connection instance every time, which means a new curl handle was created as well. I modified the library to reuse the same connection instance and that solved the problem, but I can't remember exactly which commit or how I did it.